# Newtheorem, disable textit inside math mode

Tags: amsthm

I have following command from amsthm in my document:

```
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
```

With the following usage:

```
\begin{mytheorem}

The following holds: $A = B + C$

\end{mytheorem}
```

Inside "mytheorem" everything is in textit, even letters inside $$. Can I somehow globally disable textit inside math mode in "mytheorem"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  in the example you give, the letters A, B and C are not in `\textit`; they are in a special math font that is, by definition, italic.  if you are loading `amsmath`, then any words in a `\text{...}` string *will* be in `\textit`, but math never is.  how do you want to see your math?  in an upright shape?

Comment: I've seen books where the math symbols in italic context are typeset upright. I have to say they look *mathematically* wrong: the symbol for a variable should *always* be the same.